# Check if string in firebase data exist

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to check if in my database there is the same string that I write in text field. I tried this:

```
let s = textField?.text!.lowercased()

    DataService.ds.MSGS_DB_REF_KEY1.queryOrdered(byChild: "livelli").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        for item in snapshot.children{
            if (s?.contains(item as! String))!{

            }
        }

    })
```

But this give me the error, because obviously string and FIRDataSnapshot are different things.How could I solve this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the item to a FIRDataSnapshot and get the value.

```
let s = textField?.text!.lowercased()

DataService.ds.MSGS_DB_REF_KEY1.queryOrdered(byChild: "livelli").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
    for item in snapshot.children{
        let itemSnap = item as! FIRDataSnapshot
        for child in itemSnap.children {
            childSnap = child as! FIRDataSnapshot
            if let firebaseVal = childSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "text").value as? String {
                if s?.contains(firebaseVal.lowercased()){

                }
            }
        }
    }

})
```

Comment: now is giving me another error that say I cannot convert an NSDictonaryM to String @Peter Tao

Comment: sorry NSString not String

Comment: Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryM' (0x1062922b0) to 'NSString' (0x10589dc60).

Comment: Could you screenshot how your data is structured on firebase?

Comment: updated the response and as @McCygnus said, you shouldn't force unwrap if you don't have to.

Comment: ok but where I should declare "item" in the first line of code @Peter Tao

Comment: You should still have the outer for loop as in your code snippet. I've updated the answer to reflect that. "item" id declared in `for item in snapshot.children`

Comment: Where is the error? Mind copy and pasting the error message?

Comment: I tried with an else{ print(Error.self) } but I only see the word "Error" @Peter Tao

Comment: Do you mind screenshoting the part of the database that has the matching string?

Comment: Done, I would like to see if the word in textfield is equal to string like text:level1

Comment: Ahh that makes sense. I've updated my answer. You should add in childSnapshot(forPath: "text").value because that is actually where the text is being stored.

Comment: now is giving me this: Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' (0x10994e918) to 'NSString' (0x108f60c60). @Peter Tao

Comment: Updated again. I've add in an `if let` so that is there is no text value in the database, the if statement will be skipped.

Comment: now isn't giving me errors but it isn't doing anything

Comment: Did you put something in the if statement for it to do something? Maybe print("It matched!")

Comment: yeah I did it, in if and else statement, and there isn't output @Peter Tao

Comment: What is text is in the textfield?

Comment: I write "Level 1" in textfield and I would like to make something like print("works") if in firebase data there is the same string, and the string "Level 1" is actually in database

Comment: the text is being lowercased in the first line of code, so it will not match unless you lowercase the text from firebase as well. I have updated the answer again.

Comment: Could you print the firebaseVal and tell me what's coming out?

Comment: it isn't giving me output

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the value out of the FIRDataSnapshot:

```
for item in snapshot.children{
    if let itemValue = (item as? FIRDataSnapshot).value as? String, let s = s, s.contains(itemValue){

    }
}
```

Also, don't force unwrap if you don't have to.  Safely unwrap them so that you don't risk crashes if something changes in the future.

Comment: xcode is trying to correct this line of code: if let itemValue = item.value as? String, let s = s, s.contains(itemValue) to this : if let itemValue = ((item) as AnyObject).value as? String, let s = s, s.contains(itemValue) and is giving me an error that says: "ambiguous use of value"

Comment: It's probably not identifying the type of item and it needs to be cased.  Updated answer.

Comment: this isn't working, if I add an else{ print(Error.self) }, it gives me Error